# Is there a way to hold HTTP requests to be made until the number of pending requests are less than N?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am working on something where the user can upload N number of files in one go. However, since I am also sending N parallel requests at once (1 request per file to upload) it can easily choke the server and it would start throwing 429 (Too Many Requests) error for the requests made.

Is there some way I can hold a request from being made (without blocking the UI as well) if there are already K pending requests for the same?

Here's a minimal code block to give an idea about what I'm currently doing:

```js
filesToUpload.forEach(function(file) {
    // abstract function which converts the given file to base64,
    // prepares the payload, makes a POST request and returns a promise
    upload(file, successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Comment: But you can (and should) use `formData` to append multiple files in one request

Comment: You should be using FormData anyway, rather than base64 encoding the data - the latter will increase the amount of data you need to transfer by around 4/3.

Comment: @ITgoldman In my case, there are 3rd party APIs being called in the backend which is blocking as well. So that would lead to a very high response time.

Comment: @NeerajKumar modify the API to accept multiple files!

Comment: browsers have a limit of number of parallel requests per server - (though that may not be the case for http/2) - anyway, are you actually getting a 429 error, or is this a purely hypothetical situation? and ... what is "N" anyway, what IS the limit

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I am actually getting 429 when hundreds of files are being uploaded. I also don't want to get timed out after they are in pending state for sometime

Comment: so - what is this `upload` function? seems like the wrong tool for the job (if you want to do it the easy way that is - there's a couple of good answers already)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach would be to send the HTTP request inside an async function.

> The async and await keywords enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior

The `await` keyword will wait for your post request to be completed before sending a new HTTP request to the server where these files are being stored.

You can find more information on the `async` and `await` keywords and their syntax [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: that's fine as long as what you `await` returns a `Promise` ... there's no reason to suggest that there's any promises involved in the question - the "upload" function could be anything at all, and it definitely doesn't return a Promise - also, this would be a better answer if you showed an example of code

Comment: No, this will make the upload sequential and I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

This one uses classic callbacks: allows for up to K number of parallel uploaded, and waits otherwise. The function `upload` can be converted to Promise.

```js
var filesToUpload = [
  "file1.txt",
  "file2.txt",
  "file3.txt",
  "file4.txt",
  "file5.txt",
  "file6.txt",
  "file7.txt",
  "file8.txt",
]

function upload(filename, callback) {
  // abstract function which converts the given file to base64,
  // prepares the payload, makes a POST request and returns a promise
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("<!-- uploaded " + filename);
    typeof callback === 'function' && callback()
  }, Math.random() * 1000 + 500)
}


function start_sequence(filesToUpload, maxK, callback) {
  var K = maxK;

  function do_loop(filesToUpload, callback) {

    if (!filesToUpload.length) {
      if (K == maxK) {

        // end the loop
        typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
      }
      return;
    }

    // upload now first K's
    while (K > 0) {
      K--
      var first = filesToUpload.shift();
      console.log("--> sending " + first);
      upload(first, function() {
        K++;
        do_loop(filesToUpload, callback)
      });
    }
  }

  // start the loop
  do_loop(filesToUpload, callback);

}


start_sequence(filesToUpload, 3, function() {
  console.log("all done!")
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it sequentially using recursion. This would need modifying to handle errors.

```
(function fn(files, successCallback, errorCallback){
    if(files.length){
        upload(files.shift(), (...args) => {
            successCallback(...args);
            fn(files, successCallback, errorCallback)
        }, errorCallback);
    }
})(filesToUpload, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: No, this will make the upload sequential and I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop and a queue should work out for your case.

```js
const UPLOAD_QUEUE = [];
let progress_queue = [];
const MAX_UPLOADS = 5;

throttledUpload();

function throttledUpload() {
    const max = MAX_UPLOADS - progress_queue.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < UPLOAD_QUEUE.length; i++){
        if(i > max) break;
        uploadFile(UPLOAD_QUEUE[i], i);
    }
    progress_queue = progress_queue.concat(UPLOAD_QUEUE.splice(0, max));
}

async function uploadFile(file, idx) {
    try {
        await upload(file, successCallback, errorCallback);
        throttledUpload();
    } catch (err) {
        UPLOAD_QUEUE.push(file);
    } finally {
        progress_queue.splice(idx, 1);
        throttledUpload();
    }
}
```